# arm-linux-gnueabihf-ld: unrecognized option '-Wl,--gc-sections'

Tags: linux, qt, raspberry-pi

I am cross-compiling Qt for raspberry Pi using this [link](https://medium.com/@amirmann/how-to-cross-compile-qt-for-raspberry-pi-3-on-linux-ubuntu-for-beginners-75acf2a078c) and I am facing some issues. When doing `sudo make` I get the following:

```
~/rpi-xtools/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian-x64/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-ld -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,-O1 -fuse-ld=gold -o ../../../bin/moc .obj/moc.o .obj/preprocessor.o .obj/generator.o .obj/parser.o .obj/token.o .obj/main.o   -L/home/ytan/rpi-xtools/delme/qtbase/lib -lQt5Bootstrap -lpthread 
/home/ytan/rpi-xtools/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian-x64/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-ld: unrecognized option '-Wl,--gc-sections'
```

I know that `-Wl,--gc-sections` is a command to arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ and not arm-linux-gnueabihf-ld, but I don't know which Makefile I should dive into to change arm-linux-gnueabihf-ld to arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++.

I seek thee desperately, O' mysterious dwellers of the web.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> arm-linux-gnueabihf-ld: unrecognized option '-Wl,--gc-sections'
> ```

You are invoking the linker directly. The linker gets `--gc-sections`, not `-Wl,--gc-sections`.

If you were linking through the compiler driver, then you would use `-Wl,--gc-sections`. That recipe would look something like `arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc ... -o moc -Wl,--gc-sections`.

Be sure your compile flags include `-ffunction-sections` and/or `-fdata-sections`.

---

> I don't know which Makefile I should dive into to change arm-linux-gnueabihf-ld to arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++.

Since the linker is being invoked directly, and if the project is setup correctly, then you should only need to:

```
    CPPFLAGS="-DNDEBUG -g2 -O3 ... " \
    CFLAGS="... -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections" \
    CXXFLAGS="... -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections" \
    LDFLAGS="... --gc-sections" \
./configure <other config options>
```

---

If you have some flexibility, then you should convert to linking through the compiler driver. It is what the Clang and GCC folks recommend, and it will make it easy to do things like test your program with sanitizers (`-fsanitize=address`, `-fsanitize=undefined`, etc). The compiler will add the proper libraries for you. Otherwise, you will need to figure them out by yourself (non-trivial on some systems, like OS X).

Comment: "You are invoking the linker directly. " <-- I know Qt is invoking the linker directly while feeding it with arguments for gcc, but I don't know why it's doing that.

Comment: "... then you should convert to linking through the compiler driver." <-- thanks for clarifying. The reason I post this is to see if someone was able to do just that.

Comment: The procedure should not be much different than the one you used for `CFLAGS`, `CXXF:AGS` and `-ffunction-sections -fdata-sections`. It is just a different [make variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Variables.html).